# Setting up a Unix ftp login alias

Tags: shell, unix, input, ftp, alias

I'm trying to set up a simple alias in my Bash shell that allows me to login to my ftp server and input my password automatically.  I'm not exactly sure what the syntax should be.  I tried the following, but it failed to do the trick:

```
alias myftp='sftp user@ftp.com && sleep 4 && Mypassword$'\n''
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: I would first consider using a file called .netrc  that should live in your login directory.   You place the username and password in the file, make sure it is only readable by you.  Consult your ftp system manual - the format of the .netrc file varies especially with specialty ftp implementations.  Once set up you simply issue the command ftp servername.  .netrc requires an entry for every server.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into that and report back on my progress.